# Can't uninstall fields that depend on a module incompatible with current version

Tags: entities, 9, upgrading

I'm upgrading a site from Drupal 8 to 9. In its Drupal 8 version it used the field_collection module. There are some fields that still exist in some ghostly manner, that depend on the field_collection module. How can I get rid of these fields? The usual advice is to reinstall the missing module but I cannot reinstall field_collection as it is not compatible with Drupal 9.

Here's what I see on the status page:

```
Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
Content
The node.field_committee_with_position field needs to be uninstalled.
The node.field_councillor_with_pos field needs to be uninstalled.
The node.field_meeting_timetable field needs to be uninstalled.
```

What I've tried:

1. Running cron (has no effect)
2. Trying to delete the fields using drush

```
drush config:delete field.field.node.field_committee_with_position
 [error]  Config field.field.node.field_committee_with_position does not exist
```

(This was confirmed by doing an config export and seeing that no yaml files were created for those fields)

3. Installing the devel_entity_updates module and then running `dentup`:

```
$ drush dentup
The following updates are pending:

node entity type : 
The node.field_committee_with_position field needs to be uninstalled.
The node.field_councillor_with_pos field needs to be uninstalled.
The node.field_meeting_timetable field needs to be uninstalled.

 Do you wish to run all pending updates? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes
```

But after pressing Enter I get an error message which begins:

```
The "field_item:field_collection" plugin does not exist.
```

This is a dev site and I'm confident with running SQL commands so if there's a way I can just blitz these fields out of the database please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where we removed a module, yet fields remained. The only solution that I found was to do the following:

1. Open the DB in a DB management tool (I preferred a tool with GUI)
2. Delete the node.field_name table
3. Delete the node.revision_field_name table
4. Go to the config table, find the row related to field_name and delete it
5. Delete all cache related tables
6. Clear the cache again, just in case (I guess you can do only one of the two steps - 5 or 6)

- Make a backup of your DB before attempting
- Change field_name with the field that you want to remove

Hope it helps. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @VelizaStavrev, thanks for the answer. I did everything you said but the fields are still appearing on the status report! There were no entries for them in the config table but I dropped the node__field_* and node_revision__field_* tables for each field and I cleared the cache via drush and via the GUI and truncated all the cache__* tables as well.

Comment: I also ran cron and cleared the cache again afterwards. Still showing on status page!

Comment: I guess you already tried searching for them in the config table with the built in search by key words, not the full field name? I used DBeaver, couldn't do a good search with Heidi when trying. If that helps.

Comment: Thanks @ValizarStavrev. I am using the command line, but I did this, which is equivalent: `select * from config where data like "%committee_with%"; select * from config where name like "%committee_with%";  select * from config where collection like "%committee_with%"` - they all returned nothing